# newspaper site with joomla?

Tags: joomla

i need to create a newspaper site for a client , joomla is good enough to create such a website ?
is there other options for creating newspaper sites ?
thnx

Comment: what is a "newspaper site"? Collect your requirements and then compare them to joomla and maybe other systems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Joomla would be fine for a newspaper site. You can post articles and categorise them, add images and so on. By default articles are arranged in 2 columns on the homepage which is quite newspaper-like.

If your needs are more complex then you may find the [Joomla extensions site](http://extensions.joomla.org/) useful for additional functionality. I also suggest you take a look at the [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/) if you need some basic help.

Answer (score 1):

The Python web framework [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) was initially developed to create websites for newspapers. Of course, django will require you to do some python programming, but it will allow you to fit the solution to the needs of the business.

PS: As you asked the question on SO, I assume that you are going to develop a custom solution and not looking for a plug'n'play solution. Right?

Comment: thnx but I cant use python coz i dont know it !
I couldnt understand what you mean by custom solution ! i need to design a site for a client , he needs a newspaper site.
just want to know if its possible to use a cms like joomla to build this or not

Answer (score 0):

i will say joomla is good platform for publishing news articles, but the only one thing that i find it really annoying is that it doesn't allow you to put thumbnail next to a article.